# MySQL: identifying duplicated data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a database designed this way to store software testing data: [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMkqM.png)

I have got the INSERT and SELECT queries working fine but I faced a problem. If I test same software again on same configuration that it has been tested on before, the stored data in table `fault` isn't related to a specific test run. It is just related to a specific software and specific configuration.

To sum it up: If I test the same software on the same configuration now and a year later I want to be able to relate the found faults to specific testing time. How should I change the design?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only one proper way to fix this: you should add a table handling your *test session* atop of the *configuration* table.

For instance:

### Table test_session

```
session_id  INT
start-ts    timestamp
end-ts      timestamp
tester      VARCHAR(30)
comments    VARCHAR(200)
```

### Table configuration

```
configuration_id   INT
test_session_id    INT
configuration_name VARCHAR(45)
```

In the application you should add a mechanism to handle sessions. When you start a new session you should enter it's data somewhere and then INSERT a record in the *test_session* table, and assign its `id` to the *configuration*.

This design offers you more than just "*be able to relate the found faults to specific testing time*". You will also be able to compare the same configurations and thus have a history and see the evolution of your configurations over time

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will make a table test_session that is related to tables 'configuration' and 'fault' and delete the current relation between 'configuration' and 'fault'.